# How to seed dev database in Sails.js in a reproducible way

Tags: sails.js

I'm looking for a best way to seed my development database in sails js.

In rails I would just use the seeds.rb file but even without that I could use a rake task.

With sails I am unsure of how I could do this outside of manually doing it with sails console.

Please note that solutions which add logic to config/models and the models themselves for production seeding are not what I am looking for. I don't want these records to exist in production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can seed your database in the [`config/bootstrap.js`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-bootstrap) file.

---

To seed it for a particular environment, what I usually do is:

```
// config/bootstrap.js
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {

  if(process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'development')
    return cb();

  // Do whatever you want
  // And don't forget to...
  return cb();

};
```

And to drop the database each time during the Sails lifting:

```
// config/env/development.js
module.exports = {

  models: {
    migrate: 'drop'
  }

};
```

Comment: This actually meets my use case more directly! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use test framework, like Mocha. At your development mode, switch your table name to `development` table. Here is step by step:

1. Install `mocha` with `npm install mocha --save-dev`
2. Create `test/boostrap.test.js` and fill with (configure as your needs), look at my configured `connections`, it'll override default `connections` at `config`.

   ```
   var Sails = require('sails'),
   sails;

   before(function (done) {
     Sails.lift({
       log        : {
         level: 'error'
       },
       connections: {
         mongodbServer: {
           database: 'table_test'
         }
       },
       models     : {
         migrate: 'drop'
       }
     }, function (err, server) {
       sails = server;
       done(err, sails);
     });
   });

   after(function (done) {
     // here you can clear fixtures, etc.
     sails.lower(done);
   });
   ```
3. Create another file for seeding your data, for example create `test/inject/seed.js` and fill with something like.

   ```
   describe('data seeding', function(){
     it('should seed data', function(done){
       sails.models.someModel
         .create({
           name: 'Some Name'
         })
         .then(function(result){
           done();
         })
         .catch(done);
     });
   });
   ```
4. Add this at your `package.json` under `"scripts"` key.

   ```
   "test": "_mocha test/bootstrap.test.js test/inject/**/*.inject.js --no-timeouts"
   ```
5. Run it with `npm test` to seed your data.
6. If you need to use it at development mode, when you run `sails lift`, edit your `config/env/development.js` and add something like this.

   ```
   module.exports = {

     connections: {
       mongodbServer: {
         database: 'table_test'
       }
     }

   };
   ```
7. Now your `sails lift` will use `table_test` instead of production table, so your production table will be clean.